# classes vs interfaces in Angular(TypeScript)

Tags: angular, typescript

What are the pros and cons of using classes vs interfaces in angular ?what is the best practice and when to use classes and when to use interfaces in angular?

Comment: [First result on Google](https://toddmotto.com/classes-vs-interfaces-in-typescript).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Your question is unclear. Classes and interfaces aren't interchangeable, they do different things. So you use a class when you need a class, and you use an interface when you need an interface. Suggest reviewing the docs and then, if necessary, asking a more specific question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess, this part from the [**Angular Style Guide**](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-03-03) says it all:

> Consider using a `class` instead of an `interface` for services and declarables (components, directives, and pipes).
>
> Consider using an `interface` for data models.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to give you the short answer, that should give you the overall picture by demonstrating the key differences:

Interfaces are not compiled to javascript.

**vs**

Classes are compiled to javascript classes.

---

Interfaces are used for tooling (Intellisense/autocomplete) only.

**vs**

Classes are part of runtime program logic.