# Cost using class vs interface for memory and performance

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

When writing typescript for my angular application, I can create my domain objects with an Interface or a class. I am looking for hard data on the actual costs of using the class approach.

I know that using an interface does not generate any javascript code, but using a class does. Both approaches have the benefit of autocompletion and syntax checking.

I see more benefits of using classes
 - Easily unit tested
 - Business logic can be added to domain objects (which sounds good, when using Domain Driven Design)
 - We can force domain objects being immutable

So logically an interface is cheaper but I am trying to figure out if the costs of using a class actually outweigh the benefits.

For this I'd like to know what others' experience is in comparing the 2 approaches in a real application. Or if people know of performance tests that have been done in this area.

So far I've found this question ([classes vs interfaces in Angular(TypeScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53598807/classes-vs-interfaces-in-angulartypescript)) that suggests using an interface for my data models, but it doesn't give any hard data to be able to decide which approach would suit me best.

Comment: Depends on where you do the processing. If you apply business logic in the front-end, classes that encapsulate logic sound good. Especially if the back end is in node, you can have a shared library and re-use logic. If your processing is primarily in the backend in a different language, interfaces will provide the type-safety you need without bloating the front-code.

Comment: I don't want to decide for each domain object to either create an interface or to create a class for it. I'd like the structure of my applications' domain objects to either always be a class or always an interface but not mixed, but which approach is best, I think, depends on the costs of using classes.

Comment: Is that a reply to my comment? I made no implication that you should decide for each domain object individually, I gave you a reasoning pattern to make the choice??????

Comment: Since Interface doesn't produce any code this has 0 impact on performance etc. Also, if you want to use Class simply for type checking there is no point in that because type checking is happening only before compilation and on runtime there is no type check by class. Only if you are going to create Class instances it's worth using Class instead of Interface. Otherwise, Interface is preferred way.

Comment: @Sergey I know that interfaces don't get compiled into JS and thus has 0 impact on performance (I mentioned this in my question). I would prefer to use classes instead of interfaces for my applications' domain object (I'm referring to the domain objects from Domain Driven Design) because of the benefits (see my question). But I wish not to mix classes and Interfaces, as this will help keep my application consistent. That said, if there are huge performance or memory cost when using classes I might need to reconsider this idea. But to determine that I need to know what actual costs are.

Comment: @Avin sorry, I misunderstood you. A lot of business logic will be in the backend, but quite a bit will also be needed in the front-end to help make decisions on how to display certain data. For instance, if a specific instance of a domain object, is to be considered downloadable we could look at various properties of this object. Such logic can be business related and can become complex and the best place could be in that objects' class.

Answer (score 2):

**For super-simple data objects, use interfaces (or types).** Examples: parameter objects, value types, and any other objects that don't require any built-in logic.

**For anything more complicated, use classes.** The overhead of this choice is minimal compared to the benefits you're getting, for example the ability to put some simple logic inside the class so you don't need to off-load it into a service. The class definition takes a little bit of memory, but in runtime, a class just means a specific prototype for the objects.

I admit this answer does not include any actual performance or statistics, but those would greatly depend on the type of object and context.

Also see [this great comment on Github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19632#issuecomment-335469966).